# Entity Framework code first: update SetInitializer throws exception

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've been looking for this strange error for hours but haven't found anything. I have a very simple entity:

```
public class Company {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the context:

```
public class MyDBContext : DbContext {

    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }

}
```

When running the first time, everything works just fine. But, when I change the entity (for example, I put the [Key] attribute for Id), I get the expected "model has changed" or something error. So, I enter this in the Global.asax application_start:

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyDBContext>
(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges< MyDBContext >());
```

This is where I get stuck. There is no compile error, it compiles without errors / warnings. But, when I run my project, I get the following error:

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: `System.TypeLoadException: GenericArguments[0], 'MyDB.Data.MyDBContext', on 'System.Data.Entity.IDatabaseInitializer1[TContext]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TContext'`.

Please, does someone have a clue? I'm using Entity Framework 4.1 (CTP5)

Comment: I got a hint finally. My database context was in a Class Library project, while the Global.asax was of course in an MVC3 web application. Moving the entire database logic to the same MVC3 web application solved the issue. So why doesn't it work in the class library?

Comment: F*ck this, solved after hours. Turned out the library class was using 4.0.0 and the web application 4.0.1. Shoot me.

Comment: Sir, you just saved me guaranteed hours of banging my head against a desk. Put your answer up and I'll upvote it immediately.

Comment: If this was due to a Fusion Load error... the fusion log viewer is your friend.
I have also seen something similar 
When EF is in Auto Migration mode, it will expect a Context with parameter less constructor.

Comment: mark as answered please

Comment: possible duplicate of [TypeLoadException with DbContext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850119/typeloadexception-with-dbcontext)

Answer (score 2):

For the unanswered question trawlers, this has been answered above. But never marked by users. See comments above. Over 1K views !  Thats wasting a lot of time... So i added this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Web.config (instead of Global.asax) and multiple project files (I for example usually create in ASP.NET MVC a [*Projectname*].WebUI which contains the MVC files and a [*Projectname*].Domain which is a class library containing the data logic) then you need to add following code to ALL Web.config/App.config in your solution:

```
<configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
```

This worked for me without needing to merge my Domain project with the WebUI project.